# why doesn't WireShark show any traffic from invalid certificate https site?

Tags: router, wireshark, monitoring, traffic, certification

[image]

[image]

i have tried mobile apps like HttpCanary and pc programs like wireshark still got nothing from the site !!

Comment: Per your first screenshot, even though the certificate is invalid, the traffic will still be encrypted.

Comment: @LucasRamage  ...  but why it still doesn't work although i have installed the root ssl debugging certificate for the app !! .

Comment: This might help, https://redflagsecurity.net/2019/03/10/decrypting-tls-wireshark

Comment: @LucasRamage thanks it worked . add it as an answer pls ... and do you know how can i fix it on android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Decrypting TLS Browser Traffic With Wireshark – The Easy Way!](https://redflagsecurity.net/2019/03/10/decrypting-tls-wireshark),

> As people have started to embrace forward secrecy this broke, as having the private key is no longer enough derive the actual session key used to decrypt the data...Firefox and Chrome both support logging the symmetric session key used to encrypt TLS traffic to a file.  You can then point Wireshark at said file and presto! decrypted TLS traffic.